# LOCK CMPXCHG on non-cached memory?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

A simple question: is a LOCK CMPXCHG possible on non-cached memory, ie pages marked in the page-table as non-cached?

Comment: Why not? I don't recall anything in the manuals saying otherwise. If anything it's the cacheable memory that is treated specially.

Comment: It's possible, just slow.

Comment: It's easier with cache-coherency I think. With cache-coherency, the core simply can retain the cacheline in cache until the operation has finished.
Without, I can't imagine a more realistic way than locking the "bus".

Comment: Yes, that's how it was implemented pre-QPI. Now, there is a "virtual" analogy of the #lock signal, where an agent acts as the Quiesce master and instructs the other to not start any further transaction. See the lock section of [this very good article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/quickpath-interconnect-rules-of-the-rev/221600290?pgno=5).

Answer (score 3):

> The content of this answer closely resembles the content of [this Dr Dobbs' article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/quickpath-interconnect-rules-of-the-rev/221600290?pgno=5), particularly the "Locking" section, which I consulted to understand the locking on a QuickPath Interconnect (QPI) enabled systems.
>   As such this post has been marked as a "community wiki".

Yes, it's possible.

The 8086 had no cache but was able to [perform atomic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086.2F8088_instructions).
This was accomplished thanks to the introduction of the *#lock* signal in the [FSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus). When this signal was asserted, no *new* transaction could be started by any agent—only the locking one could be executed (actually, [not even the locking one sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_F00F_bug))—thereby [quiescing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiesce) the system.

With the introduction of caching, the need for a bus lock was reduced. The processor can operate its cache by delaying any [snooping request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) from other agents for the duration of the lock.
However, the legacy bus lock was preserved due to backwards compatibility and because the guarded variable could [span two cache rows](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures).

When the FSB was dropped in favour of [QPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect) (think of the abandonment of the hub architecture and of multi-socket systems), the *#lock* signal was dropped, too.

Now, one of the QPI agents is designed as a Quiesce Master (QM). When a processor wants a lock, it asks the QM, which in turn informs the other agents—including DMA agents—to stop any future request.
When every agent has acknowledged to the QM, it informs the lock requester that the system is locked. The atomic operation is then carried out, and upon completion, an unlock requested is presented to the QM. Finally, the QM will proceed with informing the other agents that new transactions are allowed again.
In this way, the mechanisms for locking the entire memory subsystem are still present and functional in modern designs.

Comment: Good answer. To be clear, does the discussion of the interaction of QPI and caching protocols apply to single-socket systems? It isn't clear to me. Most of the mechanics discussed are to maintain coherency between multiple sockets (where QPI is the path between them) but in a single socket system you don't have this complexity since the L3 can mostly act as the arbiter (i.e., coordinating threads mostly exchange data through L3 which is the first shared level of cache). I don't know about DMA-capable agents like video cards or stoage. Maybe they use it?

Comment: @BeeOnRope, I don't know honestly. [This document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/pcie_lockedoperations.doc) from Microsoft seems to suggest that the PCIe root complex is responsible for locking the PCIe bus. It may be controlled by the L3 cache (Acting as QM) or it may be the QM itself (is the PCIe root complex connected through QPI?)